# DRAM Memory Lines

Tags: memory, ddr, dram

I have been trying to understand DDR and DRAM memories and stumbled upon this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6Zi6P5JAj0&t=1666s)

In this video, from 20:00 to 23:00 he tells that the 8kb row buffer lines, actually come out as 64b and this 64b lines, come out of the chip as 8bits.

I am not able to understand this translation. How come 8kb translates to 64bits only and how 64bits comes out as 8bits? When 8kb translates to 64bits, are the other row buffer lines merging or where do they go?

Can someone explain how this translation happens and how is the data transferred out?

And second query, If I need to store the word "Apple" in the DRAM Chip. the binary value of the entire word will be split across the different banks in the same chip or how will it be stored? And If I want to store the same word in a DRAM Module, will the data for the word be split across multiple chips?

Please clarify both the queries.

Thanks

Comment: the 8 bits is the data

Comment: Could you please answer both the questions?

Comment: if you continue watching the video you see how the 64b is taken from the row buffer.    they do from what I saw fail to completely get you from multiple (probably not an accident they drew 16) 64b hw i/o buffers to the 8 bit external I/O.  didnt necessarily even expand ddr to dual data rate simply explained that that means data on each half clock. whether the 64b I/O is serially shifted out or not is a question.

Comment: how the information is placed across parts (or within) depends on the controller and the settings.  What controller are you using and what are the settings you are using and what does the documentation say about those settings?  Not uncommon if you have x8 parts to have 8 of them for an overall 64 bit wide memory (per bank) and the 64 bits from the processor bus, 0x1122334455667788 and each byte would go to one part 0x11 to one 0x22 and so on, how each bit is then sprayed within the rows and columns in that part is based on the architecture of that part.

Comment: if you are thinking that all ddr parts from all vendors from all generations from ddr are built exactly the same, just faster or cheaper, that would be a bad assumption IMO.  as far as the memory bus goes you want it to mate up with the cache nicely so for example not uncommon to see 64 or 72 bit wide modules and the cache lines are one or more whole multiples of 64 bits (no read-modify-writes at the dram required, do all of that in the cache ideally).  But that is also part of the system design you do have separate enables on each part.

Comment: @old_timer .. I'm sorry. I am not able to follow you. You could you explain in little steps and use simpler terms like for a beginner